# Need a password when I launch AVD in Android studio

Tags: android, passwords, android-virtual-device

The situation is shown in the following figure :

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Need to  input a  password when I launch  AVD in  Android  studio ,as the picture shows  I  don't  konw  the  password.I would like to ask how to solve this situation?